# Avoid using prepareForSegue in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dictionary, segue

In my initial view controller, I have the following code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showSearch"]) {

     [segue.destinationViewController setInitialLocation:self.locationManager.location];
 }
}
```

When a button is pressed in the initial vc, the segue labeled "showSearch" is activated and the second view controller is loaded with the data inside. The second view controller is a map, and the data are pins at certain locations, collected from the Parse database. My question is, is there anyway to avoid the initial view controller? In other words, I don't want to load up my app, then have to press a button to get to the map view. I want the map view to load first, with the pins already on the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your initial view controller by going to storyboard, selecting the view controller you want to become the new initial view controller, going to the attributes inspector, and checking "is initial view controller."

Comment: The only problem with changing the initial view controller, is that the data for the pins won't load onto the map. At the moment I have to  segue to get the data onto the map view controller, which isn't ideal.

Comment: What kind of data are we talking? If it's easy to set up just put it in viewDidLoad of the new VC

Answer (score 0):

In first view controller's viewDidLoad call the button method which is responsible for the segue to second view controller.

Comment: You should not initiate a UI presentation in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding this to the viewDidLoad.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showSearch" sender:self];
```

Not ideal, but it works. Although it works fine on my phone, it doesn't seem to work perfectly on the xcode simulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of database related code in an initial VC, but that VC isn't handling an UI, maybe  you could change your program so that the database code was separated out into its own class.  Then the map VC can be your initial VC and it can call your database class to get the data.

So, maybe you have a location manager class with a getInitialLocations method that the map VC can call to load itself with data.  Just guessing based on your description.